# How to retrieve the CNAME on Windows?

Tags: powershell, cname

I want to know if there is an existing command or script to retrieve the `Canonical Name Record` (CNAME) for a given computer or server. I would like to use this via CMD/Powershell I don't mind if such command or script uses the Windows Registry Editor (regedit).

Comment: By definition a CNAME is merely a reference to the ‘real’ name; there would be no practical way to work back from a domain name to find CNAMEs that point to it. Or do you mean you want to do a reverse-resolve (RDNS, PTR record) to get a name from the IP address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hostname` program/command should give you the DNS name of the local machine, whereas the shell command `echo %COMPUTERNAME%` should show you the NetBIOS name (which might be different).